# boost::shared_?? for non-pointer resources

Tags: c++, boost, raii, reference-counting, shared-ptr

Basically i need to do reference counting on certain resources (like an integer index) that are not inmediately equivalent to a pointer/address semantic; basically i need to pass around the resource around, and call certain custom function when the count reaches zero. Also the way to read/write access to the resource is not a simple pointer derreference operation but something more complex. I don't think boost::shared_ptr will fit the bill here, but maybe i'm missing some other boost equivalent class i might use?

example of what i need to do:

```
struct NonPointerResource
{
   NonPointerResource(int a) : rec(a) {} 

   int rec;
}

int createResource ()
{
   data BasicResource("get/resource");
   boost::shared_resource< MonPointerResource > r( BasicResource.getId() , 
    boost::function< BasicResource::RemoveId >() );
   TypicalUsage( r );
}  
//when r goes out of scope, it will call BasicResource::RemoveId( NonPointerResource& ) or something similar


int TypicalUsage( boost::shared_resource< NonPointerResource > r )
{
   data* d = access_object( r );
   // do something with d
}
```

Comment: Just for your information,
[here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/smart_ptr/sp_techniques.html#handle)
is a small example about the use of `shared_ptr<void>` as a counted handle.
But unfortunately, it is certain that this doesn't have ideal usablity...

Comment: @Ise, please write this as an answer so i can set it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/smart_ptr/sp_techniques.html#handle)
is a small example about the use of `shared_ptr<void>` as a counted handle.
Preparing proper create/delete functions enables us to use
`shared_ptr<void>` as *any* resource handle in a sense.
However, as you can see, since this is weakly typed, the use of it causes us
inconvenience in some degree...

Comment: yes. Also accessing the resource will be a problem but there is no way out. thanks

Answer (score 5):

Allocate NonPointerResource on the heap and just give it a destructor as normal.

Comment: This is usually the best solution because it separates the reference counting (which is not trivial especially if it is to be thread-safe) from the resource management. The `NonPointerResource` class can then be non-copyable unless there are well-defined copying semantics for the underlying resource.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe boost::intrusive_ptr could fit the bill. Here's a `RefCounted` base class and ancillary functions that I'm using in some of my code. Instead of `delete ptr` you can specify whatever operation you need.

```
struct RefCounted {
    int refCount;

    RefCounted() : refCount(0) {}
    virtual ~RefCounted() { assert(refCount==0); }
};

// boost::intrusive_ptr expects the following functions to be defined:
inline
void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(RefCounted* ptr) { ++ptr->refCount; }

inline
void intrusive_ptr_release(RefCounted* ptr) { if (!--ptr->refCount) delete ptr; }
```

With that in place you can then have

```
boost::intrusive_ptr<DerivedFromRefCounted> myResource = ...
```

Comment: The count doesn't need to be `mutable`.

Comment: Yes, I wondered about that -- I just pasted it from some working code I had. Mutable now removed.